# New challenge genre proposal: Memory Golf

Tags: discussion, new-genre

### Overview

Sometimes in the real world, you're in a situation where you need to run a program on a very specialized computer, and you don't care how long it takes to run, but the computer has very limited memory. So, rather than optimizing for speed, you have to optimize for low memory footprint.

The point of this challenge genre would be to pose challenges where getting a small program or a fast program may not be challenging, but trying to use as little memory as possible to solve the problem is an interesting goal.

### Winning

Here are some examples of objective winning criteria for this genre:

- lowest peak memory usage
- lowest average memory usage
- lowest peak stack size (for stack-based languages; could be expanded to other languages by enforcing use of a stack for all memory allocation/deallocation; tape-based languages like brainfuck would have lowest maximal tape position)

More than likely, like [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code), the memory usage will be measured on the challenge author's computer. Luckily, there are some [helpful tools](http://valgrind.org/) and loads of useful SO/SE questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080461/peak-memory-measurement-of-long-running-process-in-linux), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774556/peak-memory-usage-of-a-linux-unix-process), [3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77370/how-to-measure-on-linux-the-peak-memory-of-an-application-after-has-ended)) to help the challenge author in measuring memory usage.

Additionally, some custom memory management tools/libraries could be written to get realtime information about memory allocation and deallocation (like by writing a custom `malloc` function in C).

### Tag name

I propose the tag name for this genre be [memory-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memory-golf).

### Request for comments

- What other details/requirements would need to be added?
- What other winning criteria could be used?
- What issues are present in this proposal that my sleepy brain isn't catching?

Comment: Some language's interpreters have a massive amount of memory overhead which might make it really hard to get accurate results. Maybe something like the GOLF CPU would help to determine objective scores?

Comment: There's also the possibility of scoring by space complexity, but that should definitely be distinguished from counting raw bytes, much like we have [tag:fastest-code] and [tag:fastest-algorithm]. I'm also not a huge fan of calling what you're proposing [tag:memory-golf], but unfortunately I don't have the better suggestion either right now.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Another winning criteria I was considering would involve only counting the memory used by the program, so the startup memory usage by the interpreter wouldn't be counted. I couldn't think of how to put that into words last night.

Comment: I suppose you could compare the memory usage for the smallest sensible problem instance with the memory usage for a large problem instance. Although this might be gameable I suppose...

Comment: @MartinBüttner Another thing to consider is that the advantages that languages like C and ASM have (by virtue of being "closer to the metal") in this type of challenge is virtually no different than the advantages that golfing languages have in code golf. The important thing to remember is that a challenge is also a competition within languages, not just a competition between languages.

Comment: Of course it is. I didn't mean to imply that the overhead of a language's interpreter is unfair. But that it might be a lot larger than the memory used for the actual problem in some cases, and that it could vary based on the system state, which would make comparisons within the language itself harder.

Comment: I'd argue for [tag:smallest-space] to be the tag name (and its counterpart [tag:space-complexity])

Comment: With apologies to Bill Gates, we could call it [640k-golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/640k-golf)

Comment: For what it's worth, I think this is an **AWESOME** new tag and can't wait to use it ;)

Comment: @JAtkin I plan on sandboxing a challenge for the tag soon, once I work out all the details of measuring memory usage fairly.

Comment: I don't think the memory is practically usually measured in space complexity, but in the form f(n)+o(f(n)) (or f(n)+O(g(n))), where f(n) is a function that usually appeared in a complexity, with a constant factor.

Comment: Maybe use a VM to calculate?

Comment: I like this idea, but a Python runtime doing literally nothing allocates *21 megabytes*, and Ruby uses *12 megs*. For instance, Pyth is written in Python and needs Python's runtime, and GS uses Ruby. "Don't use those languages!", you say, but not a lot of languages are implemented in (memory-efficient) C, and the ones that are happen to be less popular. This seems like a great challenge, but there aren't that many Assembler programmers here (are there?).

Comment: On the other hand, `gforth` only uses 2 mb, and I bet I could craft a super minimal implementation for bytecode

Comment: What about considering only memmory alocated by the program itself (i.e. sum of memory cost of declared variables/objects and/or data stack)?

Comment: @cat What if we had different "pars" for different languages.

Comment: My god this is old. @PyRulez What do you mean by that? Handicaps?

Comment: @dnep That would take quite a lot of work and time on behalf of the answer writer, analyzing profiling graphs and comparing sets of data, on top of writing the code itself

Comment: @cat yeah, handicaps for different languages/interpreters

Comment: @PyRulez all you have to do is create a program that can run interpreters which process input from STDIN, profile their memory usage while doing nothing at all across a few instances, average and make note of this data for specific ***patchlevel versions*** of the interpreter (because memory allocation for e.g. CPython can change without affecting the behaviour), then execute challenge submissions, profile and average their memory usage data, and give a web server for it a nice HTML frontend on http://github.io